# Django-channels Is it possible to send a message and wait for a response?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

There is a very handy way to send a message and wait for a backward message in django-channels testing module:

```
from channels.testing import WebsocketCommunicator

communicator = WebsocketCommunicator(app, url)
connected, subprotocol = await communicator.connect()
await communicator.send_json_to(data=my_data)
resp = await communicator.receive_json_from(timeout=my_timeout)
```

Is it possible to write code of real consumer in same style? I mean something like that:

```
class MyConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def some_method():
        await self.send_json(some_json)
        response = await self.receive_json(timeout=some_timeout)
        # do something with response
```

Comment: you probably need to write another method to handle the response message

Comment: Hi. Handling the response in another method has no logical connection to the current method. That means I have no place to handle timeout and I need to store my data in consumer attribute and make sure, no other method will otherwirte this data.

Comment: I'm also looking for solution to this